# Java - How do I get a all the selected values from a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, java-7

A struggling Java newbie here - help! I'm trying to:
- Get all the selected values from a JList
- Create an ArrayList from those values

It seems getSelectedValues is deprecated?

Answer (score 14):

Until JDK 1.6 (deprecated in 1.7):

- `public Object[]` [`getSelectedValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValues%28%29)

New since JDK 1.7:

- `public List<E>` [`getSelectedValuesList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29)

  > Returns a list of all the selected items, in increasing order based on their indices in the list.

Answer (score 8):

As of JDK1.7 it was replaced with `public List<E> getSelectedValuesList()`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29

Answer (score 5):

use [getSelectedValuesList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29) instead.

So, use `public List<E> getSelectedValuesList()`.

It returns:

> Returns a list of all the selected items, in increasing order based on their indices in the list.

Answer (score 5):

Please use `getSelectedValuesList`. Here is the link to the API documentation [getSelectedValuesList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectedValue%28java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29).